# Digitizing custom road for ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, digitizing

I've built my network and now I am creating custom bus routes. However, one of my bus routes makes a stop on a private road that I had not realized was included in my network.

How should I go about adding this private road into my network?

I created my network from a geodatabase, created the feature dataset and then imported two cities road shapefiles as feature classes into my dataset.

Is digitizing my original shapefile my next route or is there an easier way?

Comment: I assume you are using ArcGis; You should be able to edit the network adding a new road provided you have a Standard license level. The new section will be automatically added to the network, if not use the Network Analyst toolbar to break existing/include this new route.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson:

> You should be able to edit the network adding a new road provided you
>   have a Standard license level. The new section will be automatically
>   added to the network, if not use the Network Analyst toolbar to break
>   existing/include this new route.